# Trying to get property of non-object laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-5.4, laravel-upgrade

We have a project upgraded from laravel v 5.1  to v 5.4
and many issues and bugs appear after upgrade anyway have this one

```
Trying to get property of non-object for index.blade.php
```

and this is the code

```
<tbody>
 @foreach($routeFEmails as $routeFEmail)

 <tr>
 <td>{{ $routeFEmail->id }}</td>
 <td>{{ $routeFEmail->routeF->id }} ({{ $routeFEmail->routeF->vessel_name }})</td>
 <td>{{ $routeFEmail->creator->type }}:&nbsp;{{ $routeFEmail->creator->first_name }} {{ $routeFEmail->creator->last_name }}</td>
 <td>{{ $routeFEmail->status }}</td>
 <td>{{ $routeFEmail->created_at->format('Y-m-d H:i') }}</td>
  </tr>
  @endforeach
 </tbody>
```

i check model and no value from what mention is null no NULL

i did also

```
php artisan cache:clear 
php artisan route:clear 
php artisan view:clear
```

and this is a function in co controller

```
public function index()
{
    $routeFEmails = RouteFEmail::orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(10);
    return view('backend.route_f_emails.index', compact('routeFEmails'));
}
```

HOW I CAN FIX THIS ? :(

Comment: Post Controller Code where `$routeFEmails` is assigned with values..

Comment: OK Its added to question

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with `compact()`, Return type of compact() is array [[Read Here]](http://php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php), so when you are passing `compact('routeFEmails')` it is converting object to array.

In `index.blade.php` you are accessing values of $routeFEmails as object. So you can try one of below solutions.

**Solution 1**

Write `<td>{{ $routeFEmail['id'] }}</td>` instead of `<td>{{ $routeFEmail->id }}</td>`

OR

**Solution 2**

Write

```
return view('backend.route_f_emails.index', ['routeFEmails'=>$routeFEmails]);
```

instead of

```
return view('backend.route_f_emails.index', compact('routeFEmails'));
```

Comment: Can I know why this happened ??

Comment: compact() is actually php function, not laravel. So I am not sure what is problem.Solution provided to you is just alternate way to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

trying to get a property on a non object means that the $routeFEmail is not an object not that some of it's properties like id is null.
Also the part

```
$routeFEmail->routeF
```

could be null ( My guess that the problem is there)
you can skip it with

```
@if( !is_null($routeFEmail->routeF) )
write something 
@endif
```

or even dd if it is null